# Shortcut in TeXStudio "right, right, space"

Tags: macros, texstudio

This is probably an easy answer/has already been answered but I can't seem to find it.

I've made macros that type things such as `\delta`, via

`Macros` -> `Edit Macros` -> `Add`

I can also custom place the cursor with the use of `%|`.
But how to I create a macro that moves the cursor to the right by two, the inserts a space?

Comment: Though I don't know the answer, I have a question. Do you think inserting a key combination for 3 simple key presses is more efficient? I mean it takes me less than a second to hit those keys and get my hands back to the base position.

Comment: Lol it might seem like overkill, but for taking lecture notes real-time this can make a world of difference :)
Like setting this as ALT + SHIFT + Z, you're pressing one key in a sense... and it's more about hand positioning than key pressing imho

Comment: Then get a decent keyboard layout. I don't have to move my hands far from base position to hit any navigation key :) And ALT+SHIFT+Z are three keys which have to be pressed at once, which is far more difficult than hitting three keys after another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `Macros` -> `Edit Macros`, 
you can try pasting in the following:

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.movePosition(2, cursorEnums.Right)
editor.insertSnippet(" ");
```

The relevant functions can be found in the user manual of TeXstudio, under [section 4.5.3](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) Script Macros.

Then save it to a convenient key combination that you like.

Comment: perfect. I really should get in the habit of 'CTRL + F'ing the manual... ;)